# Using bootstrap button dropdowns with knockout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm attempting to use bootstrap's nicely styled [button dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) with knockout. Unfortunately the dropdowns are built using links rather than `<select>` and knockout-bootstrap doesn't have any handlers that help.

I've been able to get all the stylings to work (button type, icons, selected/deselected). But, I still can't get the click function to work:

**[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/StephenEdmondson/VMmjp/4/)**

```
<div class="btn-group">
<!-- Change button type based on status -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-bind="css: {'btn-default' : status().statusName=='Matched', 'btn-danger' : status().statusName=='None', 'btn-info' : status().statusName=='Set'}" data-toggle="dropdown">

  <!-- Add Glyph based on status -->
  <span class="glyphicon" data-bind="css: {'glyphicon-ok' : status().statusName=='Matched', 'glyphicon-remove' : status().statusName=='None', 'glyphicon-list' : status().statusName=='Set'}"></span> <span data-bind="text: status().statusName"> </span> <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<!-- Loop for status -->
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: $root.availableStatus">
  <!-- Disable item if selected -->
  <li data-bind="css: {'disabled' : statusName==$parent.status().statusName}">
    <!-- Not working -->
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.updateStatus"><span class="glyphicon" data-bind="css: {'glyphicon-ok' : statusName=='Matched', 'glyphicon-remove' : statusName=='None', 'glyphicon-list' : statusName=='Set'}"></span> <span data-bind="text: statusName"></span></a>]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Modified JS Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/VMmjp/8/)

## Steps to reproduce

1. Get rid of `updateStatus` function on your `$root`. You don't need it for this simple task.
2. Bind the `click` event to `$parent.status`.

   We want the `status` function (a `ko.observable`) on the current `Article` to be called. At the point where the anchor is defined, the context parent is the `Article`, so you want to use `$parent.status`. The current context, which is the element of `$root.availableStatus` being clicked, is the argument that will be passed to the `status` function.

   ```
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.status">...</a>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help you (i don't see refs in your fiddle) :

> Button dropdowns require the [Bootstrap dropdown plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#dropdowns) to function.

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

Comment: It's apart of the minified bootstrap js. You can see it in the non-min [here](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.js).