# Bootstrap dropdown-toggle and selection with knockout binding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to select the selection programatically in the button as well as dropdown on loading the page (based on previous selection saved to cookie).

When I do the below code, it just shows the drop down, I want to execute the click event and related code/page changes.

$(".dropdown-menu").dropdown("toggle");

How can I do it.

```html
    <div class="btn-group"  >
   <button type="button" id="activeGrouping" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span data-bind="if: view()==1">No grouping</span>
    <span data-bind="if: view()==2">Group by subject</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="groupBySubject" data-bind="click: $root.toggleView(2)">Group by subject</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="noGrouping" data-bind="click: $root.toggleView(1)">No grouping</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623348/using-bootstrap-button-dropdowns-with-knockout will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Knockout, you don't fiddle with the DOM. You model your application state and manipulate the model. Knockout bindings take care of updating the UI.

To change which item is selected, you just set the bound variable (`view`). In the example, the dropdown will start with no value, and then it will be given the value we want.

```js
vm = {
  view: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Simulating fetching from cookie and setting
setTimeout(() => vm.view(2), 500);
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" id="activeGrouping" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span data-bind="if: view()==1">No grouping</span>
    <span data-bind="if: view()==2">Group by subject</span>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" id="groupBySubject" data-bind="click: () => view(2)">Group by subject</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="noGrouping" data-bind="click: () => view(1)">No grouping</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please answer the following 
1. Why are you using the syntax --> data-bind="click: () => view(2)" and what is the advantage over data-bind="click: view(2)"
2. Why are you using setTimeout(() => vm.view(2), 500);

Comment: 1. Click binding should take a function, not a snippet of code. If you use `click: view(2)`, that will be executed at startup as well as on each click... 2. I use `setTimeout` so you can see things change from the initial state. It's purely for demonstration.